# How do you calculate the force exerted by the fluid on an object because of the Coanda effect?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

Specifically, this is for the context of hydrodynamic levitation. Below is what I believe the forces acting on the ball are: [image]

What equation would be used to calculate R, the force from the Coanda effect?

My logic above, by the way, is that since the ball exerts a force on the water that causes it to go to the right and downward, the water must be exerting an equal and opposite reaction force that causes the ball to be pushed upward and toward the left.